# Difference between stage.width and stage.stageWidth

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

In actionscript 3 (as3)
What is the difference between calling stage.width and stage.stageWidth

This was something I remember I got confused about in the past (Adobe's api docs are an artform in obfuscation :) ). Thought I should post it on stackoverflow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stage resizing and getting the right variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753796/stage-resizing-and-getting-the-right-variable)

Comment: Yes that link was a more roundabout way of getting to the same type of question, what is the difference between this variable and that. It is probably a duplicate of many questions but always in relation to a different set of problems as opposed to asking outright, what is the difference between those two variables

Comment: What I was looking for something like this  '**stage.stageWidth**: width of the Flash Player
**stage.width**: width of content within stage. So if you have nothing on the stage, stage.width would be 0.'

Answer (score 38, accepted):

stageWidth is basically width of the player window. You probably need this number if you want to know size of your scene.
stage.width is calculated as any other width in actionscript. This means, it is width of bounding box around child objects of the stage. For example stage.width of empty.stage is 0. Or if you have only one small square 10 px wide on scene lets say 200px wide, stageWidth is 200, but stage.width is 10

[image: .stageWidth VS .width, visually]

Comment: I should refresh my window before answering ;)

Comment: Dunno, I'd say a picture is worth a 1000 links to blog articles. Your answer is far better than the other one. :)

Comment: Picture was added much later and not by me :) Anyway, community work works best :)

Answer (score 9):

I found this article http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2009/03/18/flash-stage-width-vs-stagewidth-in-actionscript-3/ which says:

"stage.width will return the width of the content on the stage and ignore any empty pixels around the edges. So if you only have a 100 px wide rectangle on stage, your stage.width will be 100.

stage.stageWidth will give you the size of the stage, more like Stage.width in Actionscript 2. Use stage.stageWidth if you’re trying to position elements relative to the stage.

Same goes for stage.height and stage.stageHeight."